# Fetch the latest row for each date

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

My Table has several rows in each day.

Now I want to fetch the latest row for each date.

The number of rows for each day is not unpredictable.

```
id, recordTime

1, 2011-11-01 07:12:00
2, 2011-11-01 12:00:00
3, 2011-11-01 21:22:00 // fetch
4, 2018-11-02 08:00:13
5, 2018-11-02 12:00:13
6, 2018-11-02 14:00:13
7, 2018-11-02 16:00:13 //fetch
8, 2018-11-03 22:03:00 //fetch
9, 2018-11-04 12:23:00
10,2018-11-04 21:03:00 //fetch
```

My plan is like this...

1.) Order by `recordTime`

2.) group by the day of `recordTime` and get latest row????(but how???)

How do I do this????

Comment: What have you attempted so far ? Kindly edit the question to add details of your latest coding efforts.

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: SELECT
        MAX(recordTime) AS latestDateInGroupBy
    FROM
        yourTable
    GROUP BY DATE(recordTime)
    ORDER BY recordTime ASC

Comment: Here the script: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3b4be/3/0